# Переопределение метода класса до создания объекта PHP

Tags: php, классы

Есть абстрактный класс контроллера:

```
abstract class Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        //code
    }
}
```

Есть сам контроллер унаследованный от этого класса:

```
class TestController extends Controller {
    public function getNews(){
        //code
    }
}
```

Как изменить код метода, например `getNews` до создания объекта `$obj = new TestController();`?

Цель: написание плагинов для CMS, что бы любой плагин мог изменить логику работы системных классов в этой CMS.

Есть функция classkit_method_redefine, но по словам [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.classkit-method-redefine.php) она экспериментальная, то есть не желательно её использовать для больших проектов.

Comment: А разве нельзя чтобы класс плагина унаследовал-бы `TestController` и тогда getNews() будет родительский (т.е. плагина). Если такой вариант не подходит, то можно попробовать закостылять через магические методы `__get` и `__set` по поводу вызова `getNews()`

Comment: @Manitikyl в таком случае, у автора будет вопрос, как сказать CMS, чтобы она юзала тот контроллер из плагина вместо `TestController`.  Хотя, подход, конечно, более корректный. Но и еще вопрос, если несколько плагинов захотят изменить логику работы. Как, например, сделать чтобы они делали это последовательно, и тут уже нужна событийная модель поведения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Я решил проблему через роутеры, если два одинаковых роутера, то грузит последний. Правда в таком случае просто срабатывает плагин целиком вместо перезаписи методов. Но вопрос так и не решен.